# Unable to cast CCScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccscene

I am trying to load a CCScene and then change some of it's properties before using the scene. When I try to change it's properties it says [CCScene setProperty] - unrecognized selector sent to instance, even though I casted the CCScene to the correct class with the public properties!

```
#import "MainScene.h"
#import "Gameplay.h"

@implementation MainScene
-(void)play:(CCButton *)sender{
    Gameplay *gameplay = (Gameplay *)[CCBReader loadAsScene:@"Gameplay"];
    NSLog(@"%@\n",[gameplay class]);
}
@end
```

This code outputs CCScene instead of outputting Gameplay. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem of the cast. **If you peform `loadAsScene` the `CCBReader` will wrap the *Gameplay.ccb* root node into a scene.**
You can read that in the documentation:

> ... Loads a ccbi-file with the specified name and wraps it in a CCScene node.

If you use the console to print the children of this node:

```
(lldb) po scene.children
```

You will get following result:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x13a38720>(
  <Gameplay = 0x13a3f8a0 | Name = >
)
```

This shows how your gameplay class is wrapped into a `CCScene`.
If you want to access the `Gameplay` node you need to access the first child of the `CCScene`:

```
    Gameplay *gameplay = (Gameplay *)[[CCBReader loadAsScene:@"GameplayScene"] children] [0];
```

Feel free to use a different solution that doesn't do all the work in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use

```
SceneClass *sceneInstance = [CCBReader load:NSStringFromClass([SceneClass class])];
```

This results in:

```
(lldb) po sceneInstance
<SceneClass = 0x8270b70 | Name = >
```